# Estimate for the Fourier transform of a positive function in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ with $f > 0$. I would like to prove that for any $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^d \setminus\{0\}$, it holds $$|\widehat{f}(\xi) |< \widehat{f}(0).$$

Without loss of generlity, $d = 1$. According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3384318/hatfy-hatf0-for-every-y-neq-0), I first prove that we have $\leq$ for any $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Now, in order to prove that strictly inequality holds, I first show, as suggested in the answer, that the statement is true for $f$ a positive step function. Omitting the constant factor, I'm struggling to show that
$$ \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) e^{-i\xi x} \, dx  \right| \, < \, \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)  \, dx .$$

**My attempt**: Since $f \in L^1$ is positive, we may find a sequence of step functions $(f_n)$ such that $f_n \nearrow f$ pointwise as $n\to \infty$. By the monotone convergence theorem,
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) e^{-i\xi x} \, dx \, = \, \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)e^{-i\xi x} \, dx $$
and
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x) e^{-i\xi x}| \, dx \, = \, \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_n(x)e^{-i\xi x}| \, dx.$$
However, passing to the limit, the strict inequality that I have for any $f_n$ becomes no more strict.

Any suggestion how to fix that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That’s not how you use the monotone convergence theorem (since the exponential aren’t positive). You could use the dominated convergence theorem, but as you’ve noticed just taking limits doesn’t help. What you can do is take two small intervals not $2pi/z$ apart from each other. Since f is positive, and the exponential are pointed in diff directions, you can show the triangle inequality is strict. Then adding the nonstrict bound on the rest of the space gives you the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\xi\ne 0$ take $a=-arg(\hat{f}(\xi))$ so that $$| \hat{f}(\xi)|= \Re(e^{ia} \hat{f}(\xi))=\int_{\Bbb{R}^d} f(x)\cos(a-x.\xi)dx$$

$f>0$  so that $$\int_{\Bbb{R}^d} f(x)1_{\cos(a-x.\xi)<1/2} dx \ne 0$$ obtaining

$$| \hat{f}(\xi)|\le \int_{\Bbb{R}^d} f(x)1_{\cos(a-x.\xi)\ge 1/2} dx  + 1/2 \int_{\Bbb{R}^d} f(x)1_{\cos(a-x.\xi)< 1/2} dx $$
$$<\int_{\Bbb{R}^d} f(x)1_{\cos(a-x.\xi)\ge 1/2} dx  + \int_{\Bbb{R}^d} f(x)1_{\cos(a-x.\xi)< 1/2} dx=\hat{f}(0)$$
If you assume only that $f\ge 0,\|f\|_{L^1}\ne 0$ then $\{x\in \Bbb{R}^d,\cos(a-x.\xi)=1\}$ has measure zero so there is $r<1$ such that $\int_{\Bbb{R}^d} f(x)1_{\cos(a-x.\xi)< r} dx\ne 0$ and
$\hat{f}(0)-| \hat{f}(\xi)|\ge (1-r) \int_{\Bbb{R}^d} f(x)1_{\cos(a-x.\xi)< r} dx>0 $

Comment: Very useful, thanks a lot!!